# Strip <p> and <br> tags from a specific div

Tags: tags, html, customization

I don't know if its WordPress or TinyMCE but something always puts a crap load of paragraph and break tags everywhere which is incredibly annoying.

I have a div with an ID of "hover" and I want to strip out all of the paragraph and break tags from ONLY within that div.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

The code above will strip them out of everywhere on the site.. I don't want that.

I found this on another post:

```
function the_content_filter($content) {
    $block = join("|",array("one_third", "team_member"));
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[($block)(\s[^\]]+)?\](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[$2$3]",$content);
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[\/($block)](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[/$2]",$rep);
return $rep;
}
add_filter("the_content", "the_content_filter");
```

Which I changed to:

```
function the_content_filter($content) {
    return preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[(#hover)(\s[^\]]+)?\](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[$2$3]",$content);
}
```

But I can't get that to work. I just need to strip all the "p" and "br" tags from the #hover div. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: The example you have found, works for shortcodes, like `[mycode]...[/mycode]`. And you are trying to do that for a div element `<div id="hover">...</div>`. That's what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Shazzad so that gives me the answer to what that function is actually doing will does help me out with some other problems I had, but how would I go about stripping out the br and p tags from a specific div.

Comment: So no one knows the answer to this. I didn't think the answer would be so complicated.